# React Native with IntelliJ - Only cli starts and not run-android

Tags: android, intellij-idea, react-native

I've created a new React Native app with `react-native init ProjectName` and tried to run it within IntelliJ. For this I've created a new run configuration:

[image]

But after run this configuration, only `react-native start` is executed and not the actual start of the app (`react-native run-android`). Within a shell it's working, but not with IntelliJ and therefore debugging within IntelliJ is not readily possible.

I'm using the latest React Native version 0.50.1 and IntelliJ 2017.2.5.

Do you know such a problem and do you know how to fix it? For existing applications, it still worked, but not for new ones. After npm install it seems to be buggy also with existing projects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Known issue, tracked as [WEB-29569](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29569): the packager messages format has changed in **react-native 0.50.***, and WebStorm can't parse the output and start the `run` command.

As a workaround, you can try downgrading **react-native** to **0.49**.

Comment: Thanks, downgrading isn't an option and so I have to wait for the update of IntelliJ. In the meantime I work with Visual Studio Code.

Comment: There is now a fix, bit this seems to be missing in 2017.3 EAP of IntelliJ. With the latest Webstorm EAP it's working, but not with IntelliJ.